# $m ∈ Z_n \backslash Z^*_n$, RSA works but not secure

Tags: rsa

If you happen happen to have a message $m ∈ Z_n \backslash Z^*_n$, RSA works but not secure. How likely is it going to happen? $|n|=1024$ bits $|p| = 512$ bits $|q| = 512$ bits.

Comment: Since this is homework: How many elements are in $Z_n$? There are $n=p\cdot q$ right? How many elements are there in $Z_n^*$? There are $\varphi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$ right? Consequently, the *bad event* is hitting one of the $n-\varphi(n)$ elements. Is it likely to hit one of those?

Comment: @user12708: DrLecter was giving you a hint rather than asking you a question.

Comment: Yes to all of the assumptions.
So, since there n is 1024 bits, φ(n) = φ(p)φ(q), 
φ(p) = 2^512(1-1/2),
φ(q) = 2^512(1-1/2),
φ(n) = 2^512(1-1/2)*2^512(1-1/2) = (1/4)2^1024?
...

I guess my main problem was, how do I hit the bad condition?

Comment: You still have the wrong value for $\phi(p)$.  $\phi(p)$ is defined to be the number of values between 1 and $p-1$ which is relatively prime to $p$.  If $p$ is prime, how many of the values between 1 and $p-1$ are relatively prime to $p$?

Comment: Ok, now I am more confused...P is 512 bits, so it's range is 0 to 2^512? right? From there ϕ(p) is ϕ(2^512)?

Comment: $\varphi(p)$ is the number of numbers smaller than $p$ which are co-prime to $p$. $p$ is prime, so every number smaller than $p$ is co-prime to $p$ (by the definition of prime), so $\varphi(p)=p-1$.

Comment: You may find this [related question](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/does-rsa-work-for-any-message-m) interesting and helpful.

Comment: I found out what I did wrong, I was looking at it the wrong way. Thank you, having the right pointers really helps! :)

Answer (score 1):

We know that $|\mathbb{Z}_n| = p\cdot q$ and that $|\mathbb{Z}_n^*| = (p-1)(q-1)$.

So $|\mathbb{Z}_n \backslash \mathbb{Z}^*_n| = (pq) - (p-1)(q-1) = pq - pq + p + q - 1 = p + q -1$. That number is approximately $2^{513}$ given your example prime sizes.

So, out of approximately $2^{1024}$ choices for messages $m$, quite a few are bad. That said, finding one of those is [equivalent to factoring](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1008/706). The fastest known method for finding one of these bad messages is to first factor the modulus. Then you can trivially find one.

With just random guessing, each message is equally likely, so has a probability of $\frac{1}{2^{1024}}$, so the probability of finding one of these bad messages is $\frac{2^{513}}{2^{1024}} = \frac{1}{2^{511}}$.