# In RSA, what if the message 'm' to be sent equals to one of the 2 prime numbers 'p' and 'q'?

Tags: encryption, rsa

In RSA, one of the math background is:

> `m ^ φ(n) % n == 1`, where `m` is the message to be sent, `n` = `p` * `q`.

The equation is from `λ(n)` (Carmichael function), which requires `m` and `n` are co-primes.
And, since n = p * q, thus `φ(n)` = `λ(n)`, I guess. **Question 1**: is this correct?

**Question 2**: If `m` equals `p` or `q`, then `m` and `n` are not co-primes, in this case, does that means decryption will be wrong, aka. the private key owner can't correctly get original `m`?

**Question 3**: But in practice, `p` and `q` are very large prime numbers, thus `m` is very unlikely to be `p` or `q`, thus it's fine ?

Comment: [updated] Q2 is answered [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1004/555). In a nutshell: as long as $p\ne q$, the decryption is OK. This makes Q3 moot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In RSA, one of the math background is:
>
> > $m^{φ(n)}\bmod n = 1$, where $m$ is the message to be sent, $n=p*q$.

Yes. More precisely: if $m$ and $n$ are integers with $n>1$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $m^{φ(n)}\bmod n=1$, where $φ$ is [Euler's totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function). That's commonly invoked in proof of RSA, including the original RSA article: R.L. Rivest, A. Shamir, and L. Adleman's [*A Method for Obtaining Digital Signatures and Public-Key Cryptosystem*](https://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/Rsapaper.pdf).

> The equation is from $λ(n)$ ([Carmichael function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function)), which requires $m$ and $n$ are co-primes.

More precisely: $λ(n)$ is the smallest positive integer such that if $m$ and $n$ are integers with $n>1$ and $\gcd(m,n)=1$, then $m^{λ(n)}\bmod n=1$.

> since $n=p*q$, thus $φ(n)=λ(n)$, I guess.

No, that's an incorrect conclusion by analogy. If $n$ is an odd composite (as in practice) and not a prime power, then $φ(n)\neλ(n)$, and $φ(n)\,=\,2\,k\,λ(n)$ for some integer $k\ge1$. Many proofs and statements about RSA, including methods for computing a working $d$ or $e$, can use either $φ$ or $λ$; the results ($d$ or $e$) often differ, but remain correct in the sense of allowing decryption. Using $λ$ yields a condition on $(n,e,d)$ that's necessary, on top of sufficient. The original article uses $φ$. Modern standards tend to use $λ$ ([PKCS#1](https://pkcs1.grieu.fr/#page=7) allows it, [FIPS 186-4](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/FIPS/NIST.FIPS.186-4.pdf#page=62) requires it).

---

> If $m$ equals $p$ or $q$, then $m$ and $n$ are not co-primes, in this case, does that means decryption will be wrong ?

No, unless $n$ is divisible by the square of a prime (that is when $p=q$ if $n$ is the product of primes $p$ and $q$, as is often considered in RSA). See one of [these](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1004/555) [two](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/51785/555) questions.

---

Addition following [comment](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/224061)

> where does $m^{φ(n)}\bmod n=1$ come from?

Consider a [finite group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_group) with group law $\cdot$ (multiplicative notation). For any of it's element $m$, we can define the order $\operatorname{ord}(m)$ of element $m$ as the smallest strictly positive integer such that $\underbrace{m\cdot m\cdot\ldots\cdot m}_{\operatorname{ord}(m)\text{ terms}}$ is the neutral of the group. By a fundamental [theorem due to Lagrange](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_(group_theory)), the order $\operatorname{ord}(m)$ of any element $m$ in a finite group divides the number of elements in the finite group.

The integers $m\in[0,n)$ with $\gcd(m,n)=1$ form a finite group under multiplication modulo $n$ (that's the multiplicative subgroup $\mathbb Z_n^*$ of the finite ring $\mathbb Z_n$, which neutral is $1$). $φ(n)$ is, by definition, the number of such integers $m$, thus the number of elements in that finite group. Thus for all $m$ in that group, it's defined $\operatorname{ord}(m)$ such that $m^{\operatorname{ord}(m)}\bmod n=1$, and exist some integer $\ell$ (dependent on $m$) with $φ(n)=\operatorname{ord}(m)\,\ell$. It follows
$$\begin{align}
m^{φ(n)}\bmod n&=m^{\operatorname{ord}(m)\,\ell}\bmod n\\
&=\left(m^{\operatorname{ord}(m)}\right)^\ell\bmod n\\
&=1^\ell\bmod n\\\
&=1
\end{align}$$

Comment: According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function#Computing_%CE%BB(n)_with_Carmichael's_theorem, when `p != 2` or `r >= 3`, then `λ(p^r)` = `φ(p^r)`, make `r = 1` then `λ(p)` = `φ(p)`, `[1]` I think it's correct until here.  Since n = p * q, thus `φ(n)` = `φ(p)` * `φ(q)`, but since p != q, thus can't say `λ(n)` = `φ(n)`, `[2]` because `λ(n)` doesn't support  multiplication rule, aka. `λ(p * q)` != `λ(p)` * `λ(q)`, which I though is true when asking the question. So, can u confirm the `[1]` and `[2]` above?

Comment: I think the above is true, since `λ(21)` = 6, `λ(3)` = 2, `λ(7)` = 6, thus `λ(21)` != `λ(3)` * `λ(7)`.

Comment: @Eric: One of my statement was wrong in the case of prime powers, thanks for pointing that. It's hopefully fixed. Yes $λ(p^r)=φ(p^r)$ for $p\in\mathbb P$ and $r\in\mathbb N$. Yes if $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes, then $φ(n)=φ(p)\,φ(q)=(p-1)(q-1)$ , and $λ(n)=φ(n)/\gcd(p-1,q-1)$.

Comment: Ok, `λ(n)=φ(n)/gcd(p−1,q−1)` works for `n` = `21`.

Comment: I know `m ^ λ(n) % n == 1` is a property of `λ(n)`, but where does `m ^ φ(n) % n == 1` come from, since `λ(n)` is not necessary equals  to `φ(n)`? In RSA's case they never equal, since `gcd(p-1, q-1)` is at least 2, I guess.

Comment: @Eric: see final section.