# Why does decryption in RSA not fail with 2 different moduli?

Tags: rsa

In RSA, we choose $p,q$ and calculate $\phi(n)=(p-1)(q-1)$. We then choose a public key $e$, and calculate its inverse **modulo $\phi(n)$**: $d\cdot e=1 \mod(\phi(n))$.

But then, when we decrypt a ciphertext $y=x^e \mod(n)$, we use the **different modulus** $n$ rather than $\phi(n)$: $x=y^d \mod(n)$. This is equal to $x^{e\cdot d \mod(n)}$, which supposedly equals $x^1$. **But I don’t understand this last step, because we chose $d$ such that $e\cdot d=1 \mod (\phi(n))$, not such that $e\cdot d=1 \mod(n)$**

Comment: The question's notation $y=x^e\mod(n)$ and $x=y^d\mod(n)$ is not standard. RSA actually uses $y=x^e\bmod n$ and $x=y^d\bmod n$, with less space on the left of $\bmod$ and customarily no parenthesis around the single variable $n$. In this, $\bmod$ is an operator returning the remainder of the Euclidean division of its left operand by its right operand (like `%` does in C, Java, Go, at least for non-negative left argument and positive right argument). Also, it is unclear what "is equal to $x^{e\cdot d \mod(n)}$ " and what the later is.

Comment: @fgrieu, With "is equal to ..." I meant to say that $y^d \bmod n = (x^e)^d \bmod n = x^{e\cdot d} \bmod n$.

Answer (score 3):

The question assumes, wrongly, that $a^b\bmod n$ is the same as $a^{b\bmod n}$ or $a^{b\bmod n}\bmod n$. In general these are three different quantities, as demonstrated with $a=5$, $b=5$, $n=3$:
$$\begin{array}{}
a^b\bmod n&=&\left(5^5\right)\bmod 3&=&3125\bmod 3&=&2\\
a^{b\bmod n}&=&5^{(5\bmod 3)}&=&5^2&=&25\\
a^{b\bmod n}\bmod n&=&\left(5^{(5\bmod 3)}\right)\bmod 3&=&25\bmod3&=&1
\end{array}
$$
Note: going from the second to third expression of the last line uses the result obtained above.

Comment: I still don't understand why $(x^e \bmod n )^d \bmod n = x \bmod n$

Comment: @Programmer2134: That's asking why textbook RSA works, rather than why an RSA variant does not. We have multiple answers for that, including [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1006/555) which gives a simple proof valid for all messages. If we restrict to $x$ coprime with $n$ (that's most $x$), there's a simpler proof: $\left(x^e\bmod n\right)^d\bmod n$ is $x^{e\,d}\bmod n$, thus (by construction of $d$) is $x^{\phi(n)\,k+1}\bmod n$ for some $k$, thus $\left(x^{\phi(n)}\right)^kx\bmod n$, thus (since $x^{\phi(n)}\bmod n=1$ for any $x$ coprime to $n$) is $1^kx\bmod n$, thus is $x\bmod n$.

Comment: More to the point, $x\equiv y \pmod n$ does not imply $a^x\equiv a^y \pmod n$; this is why we don't take $ed \equiv 1 \pmod n$.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, $ed=1 \bmod \phi(n)$.

Comment: Actually, we have $ed \equiv 1 \pmod {\text{lcm}(p-1, q-1)}$ as being the necessary and sufficient condition on $e, d$

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to know why we use $\phi(n)$ as a modulus when calculating the keys and $n$ as a modulus when calculating the message/chiphertext. 
I was wondering the same when studying the RSA cryptosystem for the first time. The following is taken from the book [Understanding Cryptography by Chrisoph Paar on page 178.](https://www.google.de/search?q=understanding%20cryptography%20pdf)

We have the definition of the RSA keys. $$de \equiv 1 \pmod {\phi(n)}$$

Per definition of the $\phi$ function this means the following:
$$de = 1 + t*\phi(n)$$ for any integer $t$.

[Edit](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/62316/why-does-decryption-in-rsa-not-fail-with-2-different-moduli/62321#comment137921_62321): We assume that $gcd(x,n)=1$. 
Now we take a look at the decryption process. 
$$d(y) \equiv y^d \equiv (x^e)^d \equiv x^{de} \pmod n$$

It follows: 
$$x^{de} \equiv x^{1+t*\phi(n)} \equiv x^1*x^{t*\phi(n)} \equiv x*(x^{\phi(n)})^t \pmod n$$

Now take a look at [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem#Generalizations) (a generalization of Fermat's little theorem). $$x^{\phi(n)} \equiv 1 \pmod n $$

Now we can substitute and get $$x^{de} \equiv x*1^t \equiv x \pmod n$$

Comment: This proof is partial, silently assuming that $\gcd(x,n)=1$. For other $x$,  the equality $x^{\phi(n)}\bmod n=1$ does not hold. Example: $x=6$, $n=15=3\cdot5$ with $\phi(n)=2\cdot4=8$, thus $x^{\phi(n)}=1679616$, thus $x^{\phi(n)}\bmod n=1679616\bmod 15=6\ne1$. Yet, such $x$ with $0\le x<n$ and $\gcd(x,n)\ne1$ still meet $x^{e\,d}\bmod n=x$.