# RSA - are we able to encrypt into any possible ciphertext in $Z_n$ given a specific key?

Tags: encryption, rsa, cryptanalysis

Given a public key $(e,n)$, if we are free to choose the plaintext does that mean we are able to generate **any** possible ciphertext in $Z_n$ ?

Because if we were given $e$ we can say that the decryption key is $e^{-1} = k \mod n$ and then choose the ciphertext we wish to generate, say $c$,  perform $c^k$ and that shows that any ciphertext is "reachable" via encryption given a specific key and some plaintext?

Is that correct?

Edit: The question is theoretical so we assume we know both the public and the private key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does RSA work for any message M?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/1004/does-rsa-work-for-any-message-m)

Comment: @kelalaka Not exaclty, what i mean is to use the key as exponent and not the phi(n) function.

Comment: In my case the message does not have to be relatively prime to anything, it is just a message so it's not so related.

Comment: **A** decryption key is $e^{-1} \pmod {\varphi(n)}$ and **not** $e^{-1} \pmod n$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Given a public key $(e,n)$, if we are free to choose the plaintext does that mean we are able to generate **any** possible ciphertext in $Z_n$ ?

Yes

> Because if we were given $e$ we can say that the decryption key is $e^{-1} = k \mod n$

Not quite; the decryption key (which is traditionally named $d$; I'll leave it $k$ using your terminology) is related to the encryption key as $e \cdot k \equiv 1 \pmod{ \text{lcm}(p-1, q-1) }$, where $p, q$ are the prime factors of $n$, or in other words $e^{-1} = k \mod \text{lcm}(p-1, q-1)$.  Other than that detail, you're correct.

> and then choose the ciphertext we wish to generate, say $c$, perform $c^k \bmod n$ and that shows that any ciphertext is "reachable" via encryption given a specific key and some plaintext?

That is correct...