# Fermat's little theorem in RSA with CRT

Tags: rsa

I have a question about the calculation of RSA decryption with the help of the CRT (Chinese Remainder Theorem).

If $c$ is the crytogram, $m$ the message, $d$ the private key and $p, q$ the primes.
Then in RSA with CRT they use:

$m_1 = c^d \bmod p = c^{(d \bmod (p-1))} \bmod p$
with the help of  [Fermat's little theorem (FLT)](https://yandex.com/turbo?text=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FFermat%2527s_little_theorem).

But for FLT you need that $\text{gcd}(c,p)=1$
That is given if $c$ is less than $p$ because $p$ is a prime. But what is, if $c$ is bigger (because $c = m^e \bmod p*q$)? Then we can have $\text{gcd}(c,p)=p$

Does FLT also apply in this case? Or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Cryptography. Check the [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/1008/18298) by Thomas.