# Why can't rsa come out with the same cipher?

Tags: encryption, rsa, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

When $x < N$, there cannot be the same encrypted message with different outgoing messages.

But why?

Comment: I think this might cover your answer; [Does RSA work for any message M?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/1004/18298). If it is not working, i.e. there might be two distinct messages that have the same ciphertext ( as one of the reasons) then the decryption is not possible, so RSA is not working for all message $M < N$. This is not the case.

Comment: Please indicate if this answers your question. In that case we might close the question as a dupe, in the safe knowledge that you might not have an original question, but that it is already in the little knowledgebase that is [se]..